# Regarding error in deploying an application on web

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat

While deployingh the web based application on tomcat I am getting the following error, although in the class path I hava added the spring jars but still getting the issue while deploying it tomcat 5.5, Please advise

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1438)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
```

Folks Please advise what to do as I am stuck up in this issue.Please advise is there any other suggestion that you guys can advise such as manually putting the required jars..!

Answer (score 0):

You said you added the spring jars to your class path. Please check these jars are really existing in **WEB-INF/lib** folder.

Comment: I have manually added the jars also but still facing the issue..!!

Comment: Do you mean "you add these jars to apache-tomcat\webapps\yourweb\WEB-INF\lib manually"???

Comment: You should add it to the WEB-INF/lib folder within the yourApplication.war file before deploying it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, this error is an annoying Eclipse bug.  It happens to me every now and then. To get rid of it:

- Do a project clean.
- Open **Servers** view.
- Right click on the server you are using and select clean.

Hope this helps.